# Concatenating Time Spans using group by or other means

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

| ID | FromTime | ThruTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 08:00 | 08:15 |
| X | 08:15 | 08:45 |
| X | 08:45 | 09:30 |
| X | 09:45 | 10:30 |
| X | 10:30 | 11:15 |
| X | 11:45 | 12:45 |

Would like to get the following, basically concatenating consecutive time spans (where from time is same as thru time of another time span)

| ID | FromTime | ThruTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 08:00 | 09:30 |
| X | 09:45 | 11:15 |
| X | 11:45 | 12:45 |

Min/Max will ignore gaps in the time spans

```sql
Select min(fromtime), max(fromtime)
from   tablename
group by X
```

| ID | FromTime | ThruTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 08:00 | 12:45 |

Is it possible using SQL only not resorting to a function or procedure.
I thought about using the LAG function to look at the previous row but that would only work if at most 2 spans are consecutive which is not the case in the data.

Answer (score 0):

`LAG` is the function you want, to compare if the value of `FromTime` is the same as the value of `ThruTime` of the prior row, but you'll need to also then use that to create some groupings. I use an initial CTE to return a `1` when the values differ and then in a second CTE `SUM` those, giving each set a "group number". Then, finally, you can get the `MIN`/`MAX` of each `ID` ad Group value:

```sql
WITH Lags AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.FromTime,
           V.ThruTime,
           CASE V.FromTime WHEN LAG(V.ThruTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Fromtime) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NotSame
    FROM (VALUES('X',CONVERT(time(0),'08:00'),CONVERT(time(0),'08:15')),
                ('X',CONVERT(time(0),'08:15'),CONVERT(time(0),'08:45')),
                ('X',CONVERT(time(0),'08:45'),CONVERT(time(0),'09:30')),
                ('X',CONVERT(time(0),'09:45'),CONVERT(time(0),'10:30')),
                ('X',CONVERT(time(0),'10:30'),CONVERT(time(0),'11:15')),
                ('X',CONVERT(time(0),'11:45'),CONVERT(time(0),'12:45')))V(ID,FromTime,ThruTime)),
Grps AS(
    SELECT L.ID,
           L.FromTime,
           L.ThruTime,
           SUM(L.NotSame) OVER (ORDER BY L.FromTime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM Lags L)
SELECT G.ID,
       MIN(G.FromTime) AS FromTime,
       MAX(G.ThruTime) AS ThruTime
FROM Grps G
GROUP BY G.ID,
         G.Grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without grouping.

See the comments in the code for explanation

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       --We are only retaining the rows where a group ends. In the retained rows this value will be the "FromTime of the next group"
       NextFromTime = LEAD(FromTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FromTime),
       --For the very first group there is no previous group so we need this value available for that case
       MinFromTime  = MIN(FromTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FromTime ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM #YourTable
)
SELECT ID, 
       --Getting the "FromTime of the next group" for the previous group gives us the "FromTime of this group".
       --Fallback to MinFromTime if there is no previous group
       FromTime = LAG(NextFromTime, 1, MinFromTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FromTime),
       ThruTime
FROM T
WHERE NextFromTime IS NULL /*Last Group*/ OR NextFromTime > ThruTime /* or break in groups*/;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this worked very well, in the example I had replaced a composite key with multiple columns as X and making a few replacements the code worked.